# Analyticity in the neighborhood of a point(a clear proof)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function) is the definition of analytic functions in the wikipedia.

> Let $G \subset \mathbb{R}$(or $\mathbb C$) be an open subset and $x_0 \in G$. Let $f:G \to \mathbb{R}$(or $\mathbb C$) be a function such that for any $x \in G$, we always have $$f(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_n(x-x_0)^n ,$$
>   where $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n(x-x_0)^n$ is a convergent sum.
>
> (1)If $G$ is an open disk around $x_0.$
>   Then $f$ is analytic in $G$. i.e. $f$ can be written as 
>   $$f(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}b_n(x-x_1)^n ,$$
>   for any $x_1 \in G$ and $x$ in some neighborhood of $x_1$
>
> (2)Is this proposition true when $G$ is a general open set or a simply connected open set?

It seems that this is an easy exercise. But I get lost in my reasoning since I always mix up the definition of analytic functions and propositions for that. Could anybody show me a clear and rigorous proof for both real and complex cases only using properties of power series?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In (1), given $x_1\in G$, the coefficients $b_n$ depend on $x_1$. With this in mind, I think (2) is true for any open set, since the end-line of (1) says "....for any $x_1$ in $G$ and $x$ in **some** neighborhood of $x_1$."